# How to quickly disable a single job in crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I need to quickly and temporarily disable a particular job in crontab under linux. How can I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The quickest way would be to edit the crontab file (which can be done by typing `crontab -e`) and simply *comment* the job you want disabled. Comment lines in crontab start with a `#`.

```
0 0 1 * * this_job_i_want.sh

# uncomment below to enable
# 0 0 2 * * this_job_i_dont_want.sh
```

Comment: For others wondering, the command `crontab -e` will open the text editor for the current users crontab file.

Comment: If it's not possible to use the command line or directly edit the crontab file (e.g. when using DirectAdmin), you can also add a # at the beginning of the command you're trying to run: `#this_job_i_dont_want.sh`

Answer (score 19):

Simply edit your cron time to run every February 30. ;)

```
* * 30 2 * this_job_will_never_run.sh
```

This is especially helpful for those using a GUI to manage their cronjobs (i.e. cPanel, Plesk, etc.) and don't have access to the actual cron file.